# Is there any assessment tool for SQL Server, something like orachk for Oracle Database?

Tags: sql-server

I'm conducting an evaluation of the new SQL Server environments, and I would like to know if there is any good tool to perform this evaluation in an automated way. I mainly work with Oracle Database, and as a reference, I'm looking for something similar to orachk.

I've looked for something in dbatools.io, but I did not find anything like that. Is there any good tool for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may find [sp_Blitz](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/blob/main/sp_Blitz.sql) useful to do a health check. In the interest of full disclosure, I am a maintainer on the project.

I also have a post explaining how I normally use it here: [SQL Server Community Tools: How I Use sp_Blitz](https://erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server-community-tools-how-i-use-sp_blitz/)

But a basic execution to get you started would be something like this:

```
EXEC sp_Blitz
    @CheckServerInfo = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server there is no single tool that does all of what the orachk command does for an Oracle instance.

> Oracle ORAchk and Oracle EXAchk:
>
> - Automates risk identification and proactive notification before your business is impacted
> - Runs health checks based on critical and reoccurring problems
> - Presents high-level reports about your system health risks and vulnerabilities to known issues
> - Enables you to drill-down specific problems and understand their resolutions
> - Enables you to schedule recurring health checks at regular intervals
> - Sends email notifications and diff reports while running in daemon mode
> - Integrates the findings into Oracle Health Check Collections Manager and other tools of your choice
> - Runs in your environment with no need to send anything to Oracle

<sup>***Reference:** [1.2.1 Introduction to Oracle ORAchk and Oracle EXAchk](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/atnms/introduction-orachk-and-exachk.html#GUID-3714EC33-B0C9-45BC-BC46-869D6B7C8AF7) (Oracle | Docs)*</sup>

> -a | Runs all checks, including the best practice checks and the recommended patch check. If you do not specify any options, then the tools run all checks by default.

<sup>***Reference:** [A.1 Running Generic Oracle ORAchk and Oracle EXAchk Commands](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/atnms/generic-orachk-and-exachk-commands.html#GUID-277CE34A-C002-4240-AB23-62F46AE3AA4E) (Oracle | Docs)*</sup>

#### Answering Your Question

> Is there any good tool for it?

No, there is not one single command that will do it all. However, there are a multitude of tools that can assist you with your everyday DBA job on a SQL Server instance. Some of which you have already discovered.

**Following a short list:**

1. [dbatools.io](https://dbatools.io/)

   - a set of tools to assist you with everyday tasks. Database migraitons, moving logins, creating connection strings, ....
2. [Brent Ozar's First Responder Kit](https://www.brentozar.com/first-aid/)

   - a set of stored procedures that will assist you in evaluating your SQL Server's overall health.

     - sp_Blitz : Health Check
     - sp_BlitzCache : Query Tuning
     - sp_BlitzFirst : Instant Performance Check
     - ...
3. [Adam Machanic's sp_whoisactive](https://github.com/amachanic/sp_whoisactive/releases)

   - sp_WhoIsActive is a comprehensive activity monitoring stored procedure that works for all versions of SQL Server from 2005 through 2019 and Azure SQL DB.
4. **Microsoft SQL Server Tuning Advisor**

   - a built-in tool provided by Microsoft to create indexes and statistics on "naked" databases. **Please use with caution!**
5. **SQL Server 20xx Installation Center** - A built-in tool that contains multiple helpful tools in the *Tools* portion:

   - System Configuration Checker:
     *Launch a tool to check for conditions that prevent a successful SQL Server installation.*
   - Installed SQL Server features discovery report:
     *View a report of all SQL Server products and features that are installed on the local server.*
   - Microsoft Assessment and Planning (MAP) Toolkit for SQL Server:
     *The Microsoft Assessment and Planning (MAP) Toolkit can help with your migration to SQL Server by giving you a complete network inventory of SQL Server, Oracle, MSQL, and Sybase installations as part of a comprehensive process for planning and migrating legacy database instances to SQL Server 2022.*

These are only a few of the available tools. Please let me know in the comments if you are missing anything from the tool set that Oracle provides and I'll see if I can include a tool in the (link) collection.

Answer (score -1):

You can look at [Aireforge](https://www.aireforge.com/), which provides a suite of tools for managing and optimising SQL Server

Full disclosure, I work for the owner of Aireforge in a different company and use the tool during the course of my day to day